La instalacion de sdk no pasa del 24% en unity
Hola e estado intentando instalas las extensiones en de unity para poder exportar a Android pero cuando se instala todo solo queda el Android SDK Build Tools y no pasa del 24% y no se por que. Tengo unity 3.7.0.
si me pueden ayudar gracias.

Sin logs, no podemos darte una respuesta acertada. Quizás falte espacio en disco duro, quizás falle la conexión al server, quizás haya problemas con tu router. Saludos.

es importante agregar que error se muestra al tratar de instalar
